# Common model_id for two Models - Laravel 5 - Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a question that I'm looking for its answer for a while.
Well, in my Laravel Project, I have a Model `Disease` which has a belongstoMany relationship with `Recipe` and `User` Models.
I'm looking to fetch from database all **recipe** rows that have same **disease_id** as the **current logged user**. 
Is there any way to do so with Eloquent?
Thank you !

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can express concern that disease and recipe are being used in the same context.  I hope this isn't for a restaurant. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `User` model has a `diseases` relation defined:

```
public function diseases()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Disease::class);
}
```

You can get the current user and `disease_id` like this (edited to use the diseases relation on the Users model):

```
$user = Auth::user();
$disease_ids = $user->diseases()->pluck('id');
```

Then you can find the recipes with the same `disease_id` like this:

```
return Recipe::whereIn('disease_id', $disease_ids)->get();
```

Comment: The disease_id is stored on a pivot table as the user has many diseases.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
$user = Auth::user();
return Recipe::where('disease_id', $user->id)->get();
```

Comment: I'm looking to get Recipes where its disease_ids on a pivot table equals to disease_id of the user .

Comment: Can you post your models and how you are defining the relationships between them all?